# JSLink not working

Tags: jslink, sharepoint-library

We have some custom JSLink code embedded in the edit form which works if a user opens the edit form directly, say to edit properties etc.

However if the edit form is opened during the document upload process to fill in custom metadata properties the JSLink code does not work.

Any pointers would be great

Thanks

Comment: How you have added JSLink to edit form? Can you please mention the steps you followed?

Comment: Via web part properties

Comment: Go to Library --> Click on LIBRARY from ribbon --> Click on `Form Web Parts` --> Default Edit Form --> Then add JSLink on this page. Try this once and let me know if this works.